# How to genrate a 6 digit string as a primary key in django

Tags: python, django

Hello everyone I am create a e-commerce website and I want to create a unique refer code for all user's so how I can add a refer code column as a `primery key` in django and I want to creatre a refer code as 6 digit strinf like `SHIKDC`.

So please tell me how I can create a 6 digit string column as a `primary_key` in django.

I konw how to create a 6 digit random string but I want to create a unique 6 digit random key for all user so please tell me how i add this refer code column.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is generating such string, look if there are already other objects with that key, and if so, keep generating another one until the uniqness constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the possible way is to use `UUIDField` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField) 
But if you use default version of this. It will be 32 digit unique uuid number.

Another possible way to overwrite `save` method and use django's helper function `get_random_string` [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L48) to generate your 6 digit unique string. I must mention collision of this type of uuid is ( 52 digit letters ^ 6 ) you must aware of that.This could be like following

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class MyCustomModel(models.Model):
    custom_primary_key = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.custom_primary_key:
            self.custom_primary_key = get_random_string(6)
        return super(MyCustomModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @HemantPrajapat use return and also you need to replace MyCustomModel to your model name.

Comment: this is not work i am create rendom string using this `get_random_string(length=1, allowed_chars='123456')` and i am add mor then 10 row in table but i got only 5 row in table and my 5 row is not save and i also try a roe now then it delete old row of 4 id and give 4 id in new row so it is not work i am got 1,2,4,5,6 but 3 is not in my rows

Comment: length=1 and allowed_chars='123456' only allowed to generate 6 row.  may be collision happen so that rows are not generated. probability is very high in low space. why you are trying with length=1 ? you mention in your question random string of length 6  so is it appropriate use 6 ?

Comment: actually get_random_string is not safe for obvious reason you mention. In low space probability to have collision is very high. Why not try with uuid ?

Comment: please tell me this usinf uuid

Comment: @HemantPrajapat if you go to first link, you will get a sample how to use UUIDField, also for this no need to overwrite `save` function.

Comment: @HemantPrajapat if this is solved your issue can you please kindly accept this as an answer. So that other people will know about the current condition of this issue.

Comment: @HemantPrajapat can you please elaborate more what type of problem are you facing for this solution. Perhaps you are requirements details. Actually i am not getting why `UUIDField` didn't able to solve your problem. This is well accepted way to generate unique field.

Comment: @HemantPrajapat please don't take it wrong, you seems like a new user here to me. People intend to help someone who appreciate other people effort more. If any answer don't solve your problem you should not accept that as an answer this is perfectly ok but you need to give up votes to appreciate other people effort. That will increase the changes to get you answer more. People who don't accept and update in SO , i found that people don't like to reply their post in details. This is community based service. We all should appreciate others.

Answer (score 0):

Use signal in your model. For every instance you create you can do something like this.

```
def pre_save_create_order_id(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_id:
        instance.order_id = unique_order_id_generator(instance)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_create_order_id, sender=Order)



def random_string_generator(size = 10, chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))



def unique_order_id_generator(instance):
    new_id = random_string_generator()
    k = instance.__class__
    q = k.objects.filter(order_id = new_id).exists()
    if q:
        return unique_order_id_generator(instance)
    return new_id
```

Comment: you are not tell me in brif